# How to exclude cookies from the HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

Let's say your server-side architecture never needs to know about a user's cookies. Only the front-end JavaScript files ever look at them... all the storing/retrieving of cookie values is done in the JavaScript.

Is there a way to keep these cookies from being sent in the HTTP request? The reason I ask is because sometimes these cookies are very large, and can cause 413 HTTP errors since they exceed the maximum buffer size for our server.

There's no need to send cookies to the server when the server never uses them... especially when they cause problems!

Comment: It sounds like you probably want to use the HTML5 filesystem, not cookies. Or IndexDb if you need compatibility with older browsers.

Comment: very large cookies is the problem. if the server receives cookies and their size is relatively small, don't worry about sending them back and forth. if you are storing a ton of cookies, you can possibly restrict them by domain, but i would suggest to look at your cookie strategy and try to minimize their size. I am working on a system with very large size cookies right now and it's a pain for many reasons, so we are also trying to see what we need and what we can get rid of.

Comment: also, take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347877/use-cookies-without-sending-them-back-to-the-server

Comment: What happens if you set the `IsHttpOnly` flag on the unwanted cookies?  They shouldn't be sent on JavaScript-generated requests.